# Mailto link not opening if too many email addresses

Tags: windows, email, outlook, mailto

I have a mailto link that opens an email with 95 addresses in Microsoft outlook just fine on a Mac. If i use that same link on a Windows machine in Firefox, it also opens a new email in Outlook just fine. If i use IE, or Chrome on the Windows machine, the mailto link doesn't do anything - A new email does not open in Outlook.

Any ideas why this is or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no character limit in the spec so different browsers have defined different limits themselves.  There won't be a cross-browser solution to your problem.

You could do one of the following:

- Collect mail information from users in a form and send the email to all your 95 email addresses via your server
- Create an email group that all of your 95 email addresses are a part of and allow them to handle the email forwarding for you